# Запись с файла в ArrayList

Tags: java

Необходимо записать данные с файла в ArrayList, во всех примерах, где происходит запись в файл, используют проверку

```
String line = bufferReader.readLine();
while (line != null) {...}
```

Первое сомнение, почему в примерах он не работает бесконечно, если файл был не пустой. Попробовал реализовать, но у меня работает вечно, как можно сделать проверку на конец файла?

```
public static void readFromFile(String path, String filename) throws IOException {
    ArrayList<String> ip = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        File file = new File(path + "\\" + filename);
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        ip.add(br.readLine());
        while(!ip.isEmpty()) {
            ip.add(br.readLine());
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Первый блок кода не выполнится из-за того, что line - String, а не логическое значение. Прочитайте документацию к функции readLine(), там вы найдете ответ: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()

Comment: Прошу прощения, не так написал line != null, но вопрос в другом, как мне прочитать весь файл и выйти из цикла?

Comment: Обратите внимание, что вы 1) проверяете на пустоту, а не сравниваете с null 2) проверяете на пустоту вы именно коллекцию, а не только что добавленный элемент коллекции. Подсказка - присваивать значение переменной можно и в условии (например, if ((nextLine = scanner.nextLine()) == null) {...})

Comment: Зачем вы список проверяете, пустой он или нет. Конечно он будет вечно не пустой, если хоть одна строка в файле присутствует. Проверяйте то что в конкретный момент из файла прочитано.

Answer (score 0):

Можно вот так прочитать все строки

```
List<String> strings = Files.readAllLines(file.toPath());
```